# Hostname path from Application Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

How can i get hostname (for instance http://servername/myapp) from ApplicationService ?

I have to create link to a method controller to provide document download from email html body (email generated from ApplicationService

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

Comment: i don't want the current username but the current hostname

Answer (score 0):

Create config for your application module [how to create config](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Startup-Configuration#DocConfigureModules)

`public class AppModuleConfig
 {
    public string HostName { get; set; }
 }`

In your mvc web module you could set host name value for AppModule:

`Configuration.Get<AppModuleConfig>().HostName = "code to get host name from mvc web";`

Then in your application service, you can inject your AppModuleConfig and get host name value:

```
public YourService(AppModuleConfig configuration)
 {
  _configuration = configuration;
  var hostName = _configuration.HostName;
 }
```